# SQL Injection trouble SQLite Python

Tags: python, sql, security, sqlite, sql-injection

How can i correct this code to be less vulnerable to SQL injection? This is SQLite3

```
audit((cursor, connection, 0),
    "registeration error for {0}".format(username))

sql="""insert into activitylog(userid, activity, start, stop)
     values({0}, '{1}', '{2}','{3}')
    """.format(handle[2], activity, start, stop)
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use the parameter substitution that is built-in to the sqlite3 dbapi2.

```
con.execute('insert into activitylog (userid, activity, start, stop) values (?, ?, ?,?)',(handle[2], activity, start, stop))
```

You can split it onto multiple lines with the triple quote string literal like you have in your code.